# Is there a way to keep homebrew updates safe for gems with native extensions (like 'RMagick')?

Tags: macos, imagemagick, bundler, rmagick, homebrew

Is there a way to keep brew updates safe for gems with native extensions (like 'RMagick')?

The last update of ImageMagick by Homebrew has broken my bundle (while all works without it) with 'RMagick'. This is what it returns back:

```
9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.4.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/denis/code/questick/vendor/bundle/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/denis/code/questick/vendor/bundle/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep old versions of ImageMagick around when upgrading, just don't `brew cleanup imagemagick`.